# how to make anyNumber generate number,not string

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

response defined in contract dsl is simple as follows:

```
response { // (6)
    status 200 // (7)
    body(
            number: $(anyNumber())
    )
    headers { // (9)
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
```

The stub runner boot application returns this:

```
    {"number":"-1559642088"}
```

But i want the value to be number not string,like this:

```
    {"number":-1559642088}
```

Comment: This might be a bug. Can you file it in Spring Cloud Contract repo? Together with the full contract, full stub and the generated test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
response { // (6)
    status 200 // (7)
    body(
            number: parseInt($(anyNumber()))
    )
    headers { // (9)
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
```

use parseInt to convert string to number in javascript

Comment: thanks. but the code is used in spring contract dsl, then to be parsed into stubs and mappings. and parseInt is not recongnised by the parser.